# Cannot display the Second Level Array JSON

Tags: javascript, android, json, cordova, html-framework-7

I have the following data:

```
 hotlines: [
  {
    id: '1',
    description: 'Description',
    directories: [
      {
        id: '1',
        contactno: '001',

      },
      {
        id: '2',
        contactno: '002',

      }
    ],
    socialmedias: [
      {
        id: '1',
        socmed: 'facebook',

      },
      {
        id: '2',
        socmed: 'twitter',

      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I process the record I wanted by using this script based on the id forwarded.

```
<script>
  export default {
    data: function () {
      var hotlineId = this.$route.params.id;
      var currentHotline;
      var currentDirectories;
      var currentSocialMedias;
      this.$root.hotlines.forEach(function (hotline) {
        if (hotline.id === hotlineId) {
          currentHotline = hotline;
          currentDirectories = currentHotline.currentDirectories;
          currentSocialMedias = currentHotline.currentSocialMedias;
        }
      });
      return {
        hotline: currentHotline,
        directories: currentDirectories,
        socialmedias: currentSocialMedias
      };
    }
  };
</script>
```

With the code below, I was able to display the description of the hotlines.  But I wasn't able to display the data of directories and social media.  Please guide me with this concern.  TIA.

```
     <div class="block block-strong">
        {{hotline.description}}
        </p>
        <p class="row">
          <div class="list links-list">
            <ul>
              {{#each directories}}
              <li><a href="#" class="col button button-fill">{{contactno}}</a></li>
              {{/each}}
            </ul>
          </div>
        </p>
        <p class="row">
          <div class="list links-list">
            <ul>
              {{#each socialmedias}}
              <li><a href="#" class="col button button-fill">{{socmed}}</a></li>
              {{/each}}
            </ul>
          </div>
        </p>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me that in your script, when you assign currentDirectories and currentSocialMedias it should be

```
currentDirectories = currentHotline.directories;
currentSocialMedias = currentHotline.socialmedias;
```

and not

```
currentDirectories = currentHotline.currentDirectories;
currentSocialMedias = currentHotline.currentSocialMedias;
```

So the full script would be:

```
<script>
  export default {
    data: function () {
      var hotlineId = this.$route.params.id;
      var currentHotline;
      var currentDirectories;
      var currentSocialMedias;
      this.$root.hotlines.forEach(function (hotline) {
        if (hotline.id === hotlineId) {
          currentHotline = hotline;
          currentDirectories = currentHotline.directories;
          currentSocialMedias = currentHotline.socialmedias;
        }
      });
      return {
        hotline: currentHotline,
        directories: currentDirectories,
        socialmedias: currentSocialMedias
      };
    }
  };
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

@raul, I follow your instructions.  Then I apply the following changes on my code to display them.

```
     <div class="block block-strong">
        {{hotline.description}}
        </p>
        <p class="row">
          <div class="list links-list">
            <ul>
              {{#each directories}}
              <li><a href="#" class="col button button-fill">{{directories.contactno}}</a></li>
              {{/each}}
            </ul>
          </div>
        </p>
        <p class="row">
          <div class="list links-list">
            <ul>
              {{#each socialmedias}}
              <li><a href="#" class="col button button-fill">{{socialmedias.socmed}}</a></li>
              {{/each}}
            </ul>
          </div>
        </p>
      </div>
```

No description were display then I found this error on inspect

Uncaught (in promise) Error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'contactno' of undefined
    at eval (component-loader.js:50)